# Use single certificate in WS Security

Tags: web-services, soapui, ws-security

I'm working in WS-Security configurations in SOAP UI. In Signature, I have an option called "Use Single Certificate for signing" I tried checking it and unchecking it, the request are same. I don't find the differences. When should I use that option?

I tried to search on google, I couldn't find the answer. Pardon me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: you've a certificate configured? If not this option doesn't have any effect. Furthermore this option add a signature in `soap:header` (if you've a configured certificate) but your request in the `soap:body` remains the same.  `:)`.

Comment: Ya. I have certificate configured. And When I apply that certificate, it's adding security headers in the request.

Comment: So then is working as expected, this adds a `soap:header` with `WSS` header, but doesn't modify your `soap:body`. This operations is for authentication/integrity but not for change your `soap:body`.

Comment: Ya. It is working. But you know, if I change issuer signature to binary signature, the security header is different. But checking unchecking this doesn't have any changes. I wonder what is the significance of this. Can you please tell me?

Comment: @albciff BTW, it is adding `wsu:Id="id-10" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"` in  `soap:body`. May I know what do you mean by change in `soap:body`?

Comment: Sorry then I misunderstand your question, I'll take a look on.

Comment: @albciff Here is the link http://www.soapui.org/soapui-projects/ws-security.html#3-Outgoing-WS-Security-configurations The `Signature` topic

Comment: Ya, I already saw it... the description isn't it very "descriptive"... `Use Single Certificate: If checked, a single certificate will be used.`. Sorry but I really doesn't understand why is this check for. +1 for the question `:)`

Comment: @albciff :) Even I saw the `WSSecSignature` which is behind all this. It's Apache's. The simply adding this line `wssecSignature.setUseSingleCertificate(true);` and their javadoc also not descriptive. :(

Comment: Seems that specifies the type for a binary security token, take a look at this document in `3.1 Token types` section... http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0.pdf

Comment: In think that this check seems that must adds a `binarySecurityToken` in the WSS in `soap:header` like: `<wsse:BinarySecurityToken
wsu:Id="binarytoken"
ValueType="wsse:X509v3"
EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">
MIIEZzCCA9CgAwIBAgIQEmtJZc0…</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>`

Comment: @albciff Perfect Albciff. Gotcha.. As you told, the `Token types` is the change. If we use single certificate the `wsse:Reference` pointing `#X509v3 ` else it is pointing `#X509PKIPathv1`. Please answer this question, I'll accept it. :) eye opener..

Comment: I posted the answer, thanks `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little search with the OP seems that we found the answer.

This checks adds a specific `<wsse:BinarySecurityToken>` in the `<wsse:Security>` headers, specifying a certificate (in SOAPUI specific case specifying the certificate used to perform the signature).

From the [oasis spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0.pdf) we can see the definition of this element:

> 3.1 Token types
>
> This profile defines the syntax of, and processing rules for, three types of binary security token using the URI values specified in Table 2 (note that URI fragments are relative to the URI for this specification).

[image]

> 3.1.1 X509v3 Token Type
>
> The type of the end-entity that is authenticated by a certificate used in this manner is a matter of policy that is outside the scope of this specification.

In this document there is also a sample of the `<wsse:BinarySecurityToken>` node added to the `<wsse:Security>` headers, which is basically a `<wsse:BinarySecurityToken>` with a `valueType"wsse:X509v3"` attribute and the certificate codified as base64 in the text value of this node:

```
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken 
   wsu:Id="binarytoken" 
   ValueType="wsse:X509v3"
   EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">MIIEZzCCA9CgAwIBAgIQEmtJZc0…
</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Reason for coming wsu:Id in SOAP Body:

- This attribute, defined as type xsd:ID, provides a well-known
  attribute for specifying the local ID of an element.
- Used to locate elements in the message e.g. correlating signatures to
  sec. tokens
- XML Schema defines several id and referencing data types, but they
  require consumer to have or obtain schema definition.